# How can I have 4 'trays' in each side of a box with flexbox with stretching?

Tags: html, css

There is a main div (#root) in which I need 4 inner divs, each one on one side fully stretched (run code snippet to see).

Right now I'm in here:

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

#root {
  background-color: blue;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 100%;
}

.tray {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: red;
  border: thin solid black;
}

.tray-top {
  height: 48px;
  width: 100%;
}

.tray-bottom {
  height: 48px;
  width: 100%;
  align-self: flex-end;
}

.tray-left {
  width: 48px;
}

.tray-right {
  width: 48px;
}
```

```html
<div id="root">
    <div class="tray tray-top">top</div>
    <div class="tray tray-left">left</div>
    <div class="tray tray-right">right</div>
    <div class="tray tray-bottom">bottom</div>
</div>
```

Now I want `left` and `right` to stretch fully between `top` and `bottom`.

Please note that all *trays* have a fixed width (left, right) or fixed height (top, bottom).

I'd avoid nesting more divs into the existing ones.

Flexbox is not a must but I found it easy and future-proof compared to other possibilities.

Comment: use `height: calc(100% - 96px);` for left and right ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple float configuration can do this without flexbox:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

#root {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 100%;
}

.tray {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: red;
  border: thin solid black;
}

.tray-top,
.tray-bottom {
  height: 48px;
  line-height:48px;
  clear: both;
}

.tray-left,
.tray-right {
  width: 48px;
  height: calc(100% - 96px);
  float: left;
}

.tray-right {
  float: right;
}
/* to align vertically the content */
.tray-left::before,
.tray-right::before {
  content:"";
  display:inline-block;
  height:50%;
}
```

```html
<div id="root">
  <div class="tray tray-top">top</div>
  <div class="tray tray-left">left</div>
  <div class="tray tray-right">right</div>
  <div class="tray tray-bottom">bottom</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Looks good. Any chance to align "left" and "right" words to middle vertically? (Shall I raise a new question for that?)

Answer (score 2):

CSS-Grid can do that:

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

#root {
  background-color: blue;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr auto;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr auto;
  height: 100%;
}

.tray {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: red;
  border: thin solid black;
}

.tray-top {
  height: 48px;
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
}

.tray-bottom {
  height: 48px;
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
}

.tray-left {
  width: 48px;
}

.tray-right {
  width: 48px;
  grid-column:3;
}
```

```html
<div id="root">
    <div class="tray tray-top">top</div>
    <div class="tray tray-left">left</div>
    <div class="tray tray-right">right</div>
    <div class="tray tray-bottom">bottom</div>
</div>
```

Comment: unfortunately IE11 is not handling this right, do you have a patch for ie11 too?